# Complete In-Depth switch statement malfunction

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6, switch-statement

I have asked this question once before however I feel like i haven't been as thorough as can be. I am attempting to complete a very standard drill down table view hierarchy programmatically rather than using the IB to avoid unnecessary scramble due to the fact i have well over 40 different views i want to implement. I have decided to use the following switch-statement:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var VC: UITableViewController
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: VC = SecondTableViewController()
    default: ()
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

as you can see it gives me the non-initialized error, so i then proceed to make my variable an optional to fix this issue & it compiles and runs:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var VC: UITableViewController?
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: VC = SecondTableViewController()
    default: ()
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(VC!, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

however when i select the designated row (which is correct at the value of 0 after running under the debugger) it crashes with this error:

[image]

what seems to be the issue? is it the default statement within my switch? or is it the variable within my "pushViewController" method? Might i add, when i change the parameter within this method from "VC/VC!" to "UITableViewController()" like such:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var VC: UITableViewController?
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: VC = SecondTableViewController()
    default: ()
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(UITableViewController, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

it runs & functions accordingly, but when the view is pushed, it is not to the TableViewController i designated in my switch statement, rather then just a blank table view. what am i missing?

HERE IS THE CODE FOR MY SecondTableViewController :

import UIKit

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var myVariable = ["LIST OF STRINGS IN AN ARRAY"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myVariable.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var superVariable = myVariable [indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel!.text = superVariable


    return cell

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in SecondTableViewController where you didn't define an identifier for your cell. You should do something like this,

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let theData = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = theData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: now what if i want to reuse a UITableViewController subclass & just alter the data source instead of creating and initializing multiple subclasses? how do i go about that? @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman It's hard to answer that question in the abstract. Are you using any custom cells for all the table view controllers you're using now, or are you using the default UITableViewCell? Do you navigate beyond SecondViewController, or do you only go back and forth between the first one and all the others? Knowing something about what kind of data you dealing with would be helpful.

Comment: no custom cells at the moment all default UITableViewCells, and yes i do go beyond SecondViewController. like i said i have 24 original cells in my main table view, i want each cell to transition to their own table view with their own cells when selected, etc. "SecondTableViewController" is just the second view i used for my 1st cell in my 1st table view. @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman, what I meant by "beyond" is do you go forward to another controller from one of the controllers ( of which SecondTableViewController is an example) that you go to from one of your 24 cells. So from SecondTableViewController, or any of the others, do you go forward from there or only back to the table view with the 24 cells? If not, then there's no reason to have more than 2 table view controllers. You just need to pass the data that the second controller needs to do its job.

Comment: yes there are going to be 4 different controllers/views to transition/segue to for my 24 original cells. each with the ability to go back to the original controller. simple. "SecondTableViewController" was just the second view for my first cell. thats all. @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman I don't really have enough information about what your data structure is to give you very specific advice. Typically, in a master-detail type of setup, you would have custom objects, and in the first table view, you would display maybe the title of each of the objects. You would then pass the selected custom object to the detail controller, and display other attributes of that one object. If the only thing you're doing differently in the second set of table views (after the one with 24 cells) is the data they show, then you only need one table view for that, not 24.

Comment: yes thats all I'm doing different, is the data each table view shows. but each 24 cells in my original table view will have there own hierarchy. so whats the alternative to that, rather then an extensive amount of table views? you say i only need one?

Comment: @RobertTillman As I said, I can't give you more specific advice without knowing more about your data structure. I don't know what you mean by each of your 24 cells having their own hierarchy.

Comment: i mean each of my original 24 cells in my first main table view will transition into their own table views when selected. its a simple average drill down hierarchy. just like the settings app in an iPhone, when you select one row, its transitions to its next table view specific for itself. @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman If it's a simple drill down, then pass whatever detail info the next controller needs based on the selected row. You don't need a bunch of controllers to do that.

Comment: i understand that but how ow;d the coding look? after i override tableview:cellforrowatindexpath @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman This isn't related to your current post. You should ask a new question, and describe your data structure, and what you're trying to accomplish. As I've said repeatedly, I can't give you more specific advice without knowing more about what you're doing.

Comment: i just asked a more in -depth question check it out @rdelmar